# how to loop through a list where the items of the list are constantly appended in the loop?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, for-loop, search

I am new to Python. I want to write a search algorithm that can achieve the following: given a point → search a nearby point that satisfies a certain condition → use that new point to search for the next nearby new point → repeat this until no nearby new point can be found. This is my script, the `new_point_near_this_point()` is a self-defined function that returns boolean value of whether there is a nearby point satisfying a condition or not. `init_point` is the starting point.

```
lst = [init_point]
for i in lst[-1]:
    if new_point_near_this_point(i):
        lst.append(new_point)
    else:
        break
```

However, this doesn't work since it will only loop through a single initial point. I want to know how can I implement a search algorithm that can loop through a list where the items of the list are constantly appended (once per iteration) in the loop?

Comment: A `for` loop shouldn't modify a list while it's being iterated, it's very confusing and could lead to unexpected behavior. More information of what exactly you mean by `init_point` and `new_point` is required so alternative ways can be suggested

Comment: If  `new_point_near_this_point` only returns a boolean, then how will you know what the next point is?

Comment: Sorry for the original confusing codes. I have changed ```lst.append(i)``` to ```lst.append(new_point)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `new_point_near_this_point` so that it does not just return a boolean, but the nearby point that was found. Otherwise you have no way to progress to the next point.

So assuming that a point is *returned* by `new_point_near_this_point` when there is one (or `None` otherwise), you could do it like this:

```
list = []
point = init_point
while point:
    list.append(point)
    point = new_point_near_this_point(point)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the same assumption as @trincot, that `new_point_near_this_point` returns a true new point or a false value if there isn't one:

```
lst = [init_point]
for point in lst:
    if new_point := new_point_near_this_point(point):
        lst.append(new_point)
```

For example, with

```
init_point = 0
def new_point_near_this_point(point):
    if point < 5:
        return point + 1
```

you get the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.